# Recieving output text when a TensorFlow model name != x

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have made a model which detects when a person has their face to the right, left, or in the middle. I am making a prediction using the following code:

```
from keras.models import load_model
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import numpy as np

# Disable scientific notation for clarity
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

# Load the model
model = load_model('models//keras_Model.h5', compile=False)

# Load the labels
class_names = open('models//labels.txt', 'r').readlines()

# Create the array of the right shape to feed into the keras model
# The 'length' or number of images you can put into the array is
# determined by the first position in the shape tuple, in this case 1.
data = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.float32)

# Replace this with the path to your image
image = Image.open('IMG.png').convert('RGB')

# resize the image to a 224x224 with the same strategy as in TM2:
# resizing the image to be at least 224x224 and then cropping from the center
size = (224, 224)
image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)

# turn the image into a numpy array
image_array = np.asarray(image)

# Normalize the image
normalized_image_array = (image_array.astype(np.float32) / 127.0) - 1

# Load the image into the array
data[0] = normalized_image_array

# run the inference

prediction = model.predict(data)
index = np.argmax(prediction)
class_name = class_names[index]
confidence_score = prediction[0][index]

print('Class:', class_name, end='')
print('Confidence score:', confidence_score)
```

That code gives me the proper prediction. Here is the labels.txt file:

```
0 Left_Side_Face
1 Middle_Face
2 Right_Side_Face
```

What I want to do now is say for example the person has turned their head to the right side, I want to print the message 'face the computer' but when I tried doing it I failed.

Here is the code I tried:

```
if class_name == "2 Right_Side_Face":
    print('face the computer')
if class_name == "0 Left_Side_Face":
    print('face the computer')
else:
    print('Invalid class name')
    print('exiting.....')
```

The problem is that whenever I run the code above it goes to the else and print 'Invalid class name' and when I remove the else there are no errors in the code, it just skips the if statements.

**Question:**

How can I do something (print a message, alarm, etc.) when a specific class is detected by a TensorFlow model?

EDIT:
Here is the output of the script when I feed the model with a right side face image:

```
Class: 2 Right_Side_Face
Confidence score: 0.84736574
Invalid class name
exiting....
```

Comment: forgive me if I'm missing something but can you share with us how you are declaring `class_name` I only see `class_names`

Comment: @SeaverOlson ```class_name = class_names[index]``` few lines under run inference

Comment: and you're sure that if you print class_name it will give you "2 Right_Side_Face".  Please show where you print out```print('Class:', class_name, end='')
print('Confidence score:', confidence_score)```

Comment: When you use readlines() there would be an `\n` on the end of each line in the resulting strings of the array. Could this be affecting your comparison strings so they don't match?

Comment: this is the output of the script ```Class: 2 Right_Side_Face
Confidence score: 0.84736574```

Comment: @F3CP I tried making the .txt one line with all the classes with spaces in between but that didn't work either.

Comment: @SeaverOlson I will also edit the question with the output

Comment: You need to have each label on a seperate line in labels.txt like you were already doing. However when you convert it to a list using `readlines()` it will include the line break in each item, so you will need to strip this out. Try using `.rstrip()` to strip off the line break on the class_name before making the comparison.

Comment: .rstrip('\n') worked! I changed ```class_name = class_names[index]``` to ```class_name = class_names[index].rstrip('\n')```.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is because class_name is not a complete string but an int + a string: maybe do: `if str(class_name) == "2 Right_Side_Face":` instead of `if class_name == "2 Right_Side_Face":` to make sure it is a complete string before comparing or just use the index : `if index == 2: print('face the computer')`